# Java Arrays Properties

Tags: java, arrays

What does "arr.length/2" means? Is it dividing the array length by 2?

Like if I have

```
int[] arr = new int[5];
```

Then Applying :-

arr.length/2 will produce 2.5 or 2?

Comment: Yes. It divides the array length by 2. It will produce `2` because of integer division. And, you could have tried it.

Answer (score 0):

The resulting expression `arr.length/2` is equivalent to `5/2` which is equal to 2. Why not 2.5? Because you are dividing an integer by another integer. Therefore, it's integer division as opposed to float division. Now another question, why does Java behave this way? Because of something called floating-point precision. In Java, to preserve as much precision as possible, if an integer division expression results in a decimal, then to preserve as much of the result as possible, everything to the right of the decimal point is cut off. As a result, `2.5` gets cut down to `2`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @Priyanshu no problem, if you found the answer helpful then don't forget to mark it as accepted. Good luck coding!